# "My Code Isn't Working" clarification

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Occasionally, I come across a question about a bug. The question is often a good question, except that the asker says something along the lines of "it isn't working". This isn't helpful, because usually code can "not work" in many ways. It could be crashing, producing incorrect output, not producing output at all, or whatever else. Usually, I just comment asking for clarification about what exactly the code is doing, but I feel like users should be notified about this somewhere in the help pages, because it would certainly make answering faster.

Comment: Is the [help/on-topic] not enough? Note: you can quickly link to that with `[help/on-topic]` in a comment.

Comment: @MichaelT Maybe people just aren't reading the help center, but the help center doesn't directly cover it (unless I missed something), and although explaining what the code is doing wrong helps when you are answering, it may not be as obvious when asking. The point is, I still see this problem occurring.

Comment: Besides asking for clarification you should *also* flag the post. Choose "It should be closed for another reason" > "Off-topic" > "Questions seeking debugging help..." Although you cannot vote to close yet, flagging it will bring it to the attention of those people who can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly think it could help specifically having it written somewhere, even if just for us to link to.

However, I don't think the problem is a specific issue not being described within the help section.
Plenty of users have clearly not even read the help section.

Also, while the specific scenario you have outlined isn't directly written/explained within the help section, it does make it pretty clear on how to ask a good question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

> **Introduce the problem before you post any code**
>
> In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you
>   put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're
>   trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from
>   solving it yourself.

and

> **Proof-read before posting!**
>
> Now that you're ready to ask your question, take a deep breath and
>   read through it from start to finish. *Pretend you're seeing it for the
>   first time: does it make sense*?

That seems to portray that "it's not working" isn't good enough, even if it doesn't directly state it.

---

People will always ask poor questions, here, on forums all over the internet.  The only thing we can do is try to help, and if that's not possible, move on.

My way of doing it is, I comment to explain the issue (no info, no code, not clear, etc), and if they are keen and listening, and edit their question accordingly (etc), then I try to help them.
I have a fair bit of patience for users who are struggling but are at least trying, listening, and helping us help them, etc.

For those who are just demanding without putting any effort in, and wants someone to fix their problem because *we're all here for their benefit*, I move on to help someone who deserves it.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe a badge for reading "how to ask" help section? That might actually help, although I also see users who do not even try for Informed.

Comment: @kittycat3141: We have a badge for taking the tour (You [have it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=4250629)). Reading all help-pages, not so much.

Comment: I sometimes think this would be worth an automatic action, like a Plunker link requires an actual code section. When the question contains "isn't working" a dialog should require confirmation that the question contains a more detailed explanation what "isn't working" means. "Your question contains the phrase 'isn't working'. Did you explain exactly what the behavior is?"